# Actuator exposure endpoint not working in spring boot2.5.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I use springboot 2.5.2 version when I go to use actuator exposure endpoint it show me some error:

```
09:48:48.938 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning an alias
 in 'reader', line 18, column 18:
            include: *
                     ^
unexpected character found  (0)
 in 'reader', line 18, column 19:
            include: *
                      ^
```

bootstrap.yml:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: *
```

I use actuator gradle depedency in my gradle.kt, but why I am getting issue in declaration of management endpoint in yml file?

Answer (score 4):

`*` is a special character in YAML. It prefixes a value to indicate that it’s an alias. To use it as a string, as you want to do here, wrap it in quotes:

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```